# How edit label of SortableTree

Tags: reactjs, sortablejs

I'm using [react-sortable-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-tree).

I've added some buttons:

- edit: to change the name.
- add: to add children.
- remove: to remove a selected child.
- other: to add a custom child.

The idea is that when I click on the edit icon enables the option to change the name of that node and when press enter on another action disable edition.

But I don't know how to do it, I'm searching and I don't know.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="multiple-tree">
    <SortableTree
        canDrag={draggable}
        treeData={this.state.treeData}
        onChange={(treeData: any) => this.setState({ treeData })}
        generateNodeProps={() => ({
            title: "",
            buttons: [
                PencilButton,
            ],
        })}
    />
</div>
```

PencilButton:

```
import React from "react";

const editItem = () => {
    console.log("edit item clicked");
};

export const PencilButton = (
    <i className="icon-pencil fontello-custom-button" onClick={editItem} />
);
```